# AS3 / TextField on movieClip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a problem i though i could use this code, but i don't know how to give them a instance name without putting them on the stage.

```
MovieClipInstanceName.addChild(TextFieldInstanceName);
```

I do not know if there might be another way to get a TextField to a movieClip. I only work with one frame and with multiple movieClips (pages).

Comment: How do you create the textfield?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a reference to your textfield instance: `text1`, therefore you can do: `mcInstanceName.addChild(text1);` You do not need to assign it an instance name if the variable text1 is in the scope.

If you really want to add it an instance name, you can do it like this: `text1.name = "myTextField";` Then you can reference this textfield by it, just remember you have to include full or relative path. Example: `root.mcInstanceName.myTextField.text = "This is some text"; //this would assume the mcInstanceName is on the main timeline and it cointains your textfield`

Comment: The MC has no instance name either how should i do it now?

Comment: I use 'var vec:Vector.<MovieClip> = new Vector.<MovieClip>' for the movieClips. 'vec[0] = new Page1();'

Answer (score 0):

Instance name (which you define in Flash Professional IDE) is automatically created variable in which pointer to object stored. Also it paste string to object property 'name' with same value.
In your code here is your "instance name"

```
var text1:TextField = new TextField();
```

Adding objects as child to other display objects has nothing to do with changing objects instance names except them use them to target this objects.